# Why does \big\mid not work?

Tags: delimiters

It is well-known `\big\mid` throws an error. But why is it so? As far as I know, `\mid` is equivalent to `\mathrel|`, while `\lvert` and `\rvert` are equivalent to `\mathopen|` and `\mathclose|`, respectively --- just like `\vert` is equivalent to `|`. And `\lvert,\rvert`, *do* work with both `\big, \bigl` and `\bigr`. So by symmetry, I think it would make sense that `\mid` worked with `\big,\bigm` etc. as well.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
$\bigl\rvert ... \bigr\lvert$ works fine.

$\big\mid$ does not.
\end{document}
```

Note that I am not looking for a *solution* to printing a taller `\mid`; I know I could just use `\big|` or `\bigm|`. I'm just curious.

Comment: Yes, I do, but *why*? It works with `\lvert...\rvert`, and by symmetry, it *ought to* work with `\mid`, too.

Comment: I'm afraid I have no special insights into DEK's linguistic and semantic preferences... BTW, `\big|` and `\bigm|` do *not* produce the same output.

Comment: Indeed, I know that, but thanks for pointing it out if it wasn't clear enough from the question. :-)

Comment: `\big` must be followed by a delimiter; `\mid` is not a delimiter, but a relation symbol.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

- The commands `\bigl\vert`, `\bigm\vert`, and `\bigr\vert` are semantically symmetric. Incidentally, the triplets of commands `\bigl\lvert \bigl\vert \big\lvert` and `\bigr\rvert \bigr\vert \big\rvert`, respectively, produce the same output.
- It's the command `\mid` that's a bit of an outlier, semantically speaking. As @egreg has noted in a comment, `\mid` is constructed as a relation symbol and is not set up to take a size-modifying prefix.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\dots\ $\bigl\lvert \ldots \bigm| \ldots \bigr\rvert$ \dots\ works fine.

\dots\ $\bigl\vert \ldots \bigm\vert \ldots \bigr\vert$ \dots\ works just the same.

\dots\ $\bigl\vert \ldots \big| \ldots \bigr\vert$ \dots\ works too, but it isn't the same.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Once you use any of `\big` or `\bigx`, it doesn't matter whether you use `\lvert` or `\vert` -- the category code doesn't matter since the `\big` commands change it anyways. See `$+ \bigl\lvert - x$` vs `$+ \big\lvert - x$`.

Comment: @yo' - I put in that sentence as an indirect commentary on the code snippets `\bigl\rvert` and `\bigr\lvert` in the original posting. I wasn't quite sure what to make of them...

Answer (score 14):

Using `\big` is generally wrong, because it produces an ordinary atom. So one has better using `\bigl` for opening fences, `\bigr` for closing and `\bigm` for relations.

The definition of `\bigX` ultimately does `\big` anyway, but first adding the correct type. And `\big<token>` simply does

```
\left<token>
```

so we must ensure that the argument to `\bigX` is a delimiter, which `\mid` isn't.

One could, in principle, lift off this limitation for relations that we know are built upon a delimiter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\let\amsmath@bigm\bigm

\renewcommand{\bigm}[1]{%
  \ifcsname fenced@\string#1\endcsname
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\expandafter\amsmath@bigm\csname fenced@\string#1\endcsname}%
  {\amsmath@bigm#1}%
}

\newcommand{\DeclareFence}[2]{\@namedef{fenced@\string#1}{#2}}
\makeatother

\DeclareFence{\mid}{|}

\begin{document}

$\bigl\{\, x\in X \bigm\mid x\notin X \,\bigr\}$

\smallskip

$\bigl\{\, x\in X \bigm| x\notin X \,\bigr\}$

\end{document}
```

This is just a proof of concept, so I didn't attempt a generalization to `\bigm` siblings `\Bigm`, `\biggm` and `\Biggm`.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "And `\big<token>` simply does `\left<token>`". Isn't `\left` a completely different command, whose use is restricted to `\left...\right` constructions?

Comment: @Gaussler Any `\bigX` like command eventually places the argument after `\left`, for constructing the bigger fence.