# Longer symbol for ``not dividing''

Tags: symbols

Some time ago I needed a bigger `\nmid`. From

[Why does \big\mid not work?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239242/why-does-big-mid-not-work)

I found a solution by using `\bigm\vert`. Now I need the "not dividing" symbol that is a bigger than `\nmid`. I see some ways to get it bigger, but it needs to be compatible with the `\bigm\vert`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have recreated the new `\nmid` using your starting `\bigm\vert` with a `\nnmid` inserted into a macro that exactly simulates the "not dividing" larger symbol and it aligns perfectly with your `\bigm\vert`. I hope that I have answered your question.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\nnmid}{\bigm\vert\kern-1.5ex\raisebox{.4ex}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{40}{--}}}

\begin{document}
\[a\nmid b \nnmid  d\bigm\vert c\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can choose also this MWE where the minus sign it is more tickness.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\nnmid}{\bigm\vert\kern-2.2ex\raisebox{.4ex}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{40}{$-$}}}

\begin{document}
\[a\nmid b \nnmid  d\bigm\vert c\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that raisebox is not math-style-aware, may need a `mathchoice`.

Comment: @user202729 Dear I am not skillful with mathchoice. If you could add it to my reply as an edit I would appreciate it. Thank you for the advice.